# Angular - How to pass routing function to child components

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried to pass function to the child components by using @Input(), but it return error which is 'navigateSomeWhere() is not a function'

**Parent Component**

```
navigateSomeWhere() {
  this.router.navigate(['somewhere/']);
}
```

**Child Component**

```
@Input() parentFunction : Function;

// Html
<button (click)="parentFunction()">Navigate</button>
```

Comment: You have to create a custum event in the child component. And subscribe to this event on the parent component. See more here: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Send the route by parameter, where you will do the navigation.

```
.html

<myComponent myRoute="/login"></myComponent>
<myComponent myRoute="/principal"></myComponent>
<myComponent myRoute="/form"></myComponent>

---------

myComponent.ts

@Input myRoute: string;

public goToRoute(): void {
   this.router.navigate([this.myRoute]);
}


---------

myComponent.html

<button (click)="goToRoute()">Navigate</button>

---------
```

2. Create an eventEmitter that executes the function that you pass by parameter.

```
.ts

public myFunction(): void {
   this.router.navigate([this.myRoute]);
}

---------

.html

<myComponentChild [myFunction]="myFunction()"></myComponentChild>

---------

myComponent.ts

@Output myFunction = new EventEmitter();

public goToRoute(): void {
   this.myFunction.emit();
}

---------

myComponent.html

<button (click)="goToRoute()">Navigate</button>

---------
```

Comment: None of those are applicable to the Angular router module

Answer (score 0):

The router adds components using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`. For component you can add this way `@Input()` and @Output() isn't supported.

A common way to share data between components where inputs and outputs are not supported is a shared service. For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

pass route url from parent to child component and navigate from there,

parent.component.html

```
<child [routeUrl]="url"></child>
```

parent.component.ts

```
url='somewhere/';
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input routeUrl: string;


navigate() {
  this.router.navigate([this.routeUrl]);
}
```